# 5 arguments in .Internal(readLines) when 6 are needed

Tags: r

I'm using a script that modifies the `readLines` function. The code of the modified function is :

```
readLines<-function (con = stdin(), n = -1L, ok = TRUE, warn = FALSE, encoding = "unknown") 
{
    # Small change in realLines defaults  
    if (is.character(con)) {
        con <- file(con, "r")
        on.exit(close(con))
    }
    .Internal(readLines(con, n, ok, warn, encoding))
}
```

When I tried to use it I got this error:

**Error in readLines(filen, warn = FALSE) : 
  5 arguments in .Internal(readLines) when 6 are needed**

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: The error in english may help.

Comment: `Error in readlines ( filen , warn = FALSE ): 5 arguments to .Internal ( readlines ) which requires 6`

Comment: why aren't you passing a value for `skipNul` ?

Comment: thank you for your translation.

Comment: Note that the C function might have different arguments in different R versions. That's why doing this is forbidden on CRAN.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works, i just add the argument skipNul